# How to get custom data attributes values in `MenuItem` from `Select` in material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get data attribute values in `MenuItem` from material ui

```
                        <MenuItem
                          value={one.supplier_Name}
                          key={one.supplier_Name}
                          data-id={one.supplier_ID}
                        >
                          {one.supplier_Name}
                        </MenuItem>
```

from `MenuItem` when `Select` onChange event is called. I've tried

```
                     <Select 
                        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                        id="demo-simple-select"
                        value={newValues.supplier}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                        
                        console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
                        
                      }}
                       ...MenuItem here
                     </Select>
```

but I think because of there is no data attributes on select, it's logging `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`
Is there another way to get selected data attributes when `onChange` is triggered in `Select` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event parameter in your onChange handler function contains two attributes:

- *target* which references the element receiving the event,
- *currentTarget* which references the element on which the handler was attached
  Source: [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

In your case, it is counter-intuitive, but you should use *currentTarget*, because of the way Material-UI builds the DOM elements for your select:

```
onChange={(e) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.id);
}}
```

Comment: For someone who want use this approach and material-ui I just want to warn - this will not work with MUI5 (but still works in Material-UI v.4)